# Maintain custom attributes when replacing attributed text on UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I have a editable UITextView that gets loaded with an attributed String. This attributed String is loaded with custom attributes set by the app. For this reason I always add these custom attributes to the `typingAttributes` of the textView.

Whenever I'm typing text it works as expected, the text that is added has the custom attributes set, but whenever I use the predictive suggestions to replace a word, the whole word is set with no custom attributes.

As far as I know, every time the attributed text is set programmatically, the `typingAttributes` are automatically cleared. So it seems that when a predictive suggestion is selected, the text is set programmatically and for this reason I lose all my custom attributes.

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem, and after looking into this further I've found that there isn't a way to do this without private API. However, you can work around this problem in some cases by overriding `replaceCharactersInRange:withAttributedString:` in the text view's `textStorage`, and re-inserting your custom attributes there.